# How use filter in following case .

Tags: django, django-models

How would I do the following query:

**Post.objects.filter(Length('comment')>5)**

```
class Post(models.Model):   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Basically, I need to get all `posts` items having  more than 5 comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Post.objects.annotate(num_comments=Count('comment')).filter(num_comments__gt=5)
```

The method is described in the [aggregation section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/).